# Return Callback response from AsyncTask postExecute: Nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, react-native

I've created a component which downloads an Image (in the Android side) and I want to send back size details about that image (to the JS side) of my app.

Now, I can safely say that I can call my component from JS and it will respond back with data but as soon as I add in the `Async` element to download the image from an URL, read it and respond I get a `NullpointerException` as soon as I call my `callback.invoke("response text");`

My problematic code is:

```
public void loadImage(final String url, final Callback onLoadCallback)     {
    ...
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
             try {
                 theImage = Glide.with(getReactApplicationContext()).load(url[0]).asBitmap().into(-1, -1).get();
             }
             catch ...

             return null;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Void dummy) {
             if (null != theImage) {

                  onLoadCallback.invoke("Success"); //<== THIS LINE HERE
             }
         }
    }.execute(url);
    ...


}
```

Now, I get that it's because I'm trying to return on a sep thread back to the main thread via the callback but I'm not sure how in the heck I'm supposed to get the info I want back to the JS side?! This is my first attempt at a component in RN so be kind! :)

Extra Info - My React module:

```
var MY_Image = require('NativeModules').MYImage;

var myimage = {
    loadImage(url, onLoad) {
        MY_Image.loadImage(url, onLoad)
    },
};

module.exports = myimage;
```

Then in my React app view:

```
 ...
 componentDidMount: function() {
    myImage.loadImage('[URL to Image]',onLoad=> {
      console.log('Success: '+onLoad);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your callback is probably coming in null in the first place. Have you tried testing to see if it's null before you even call the AsyncTask?

Comment: I've done a bit more work and I *might* have it covered @drschultz - just checking my solution out and I hope to be able to post more info soon!

Comment: found something in @johanneslumpe 's `react-native-fs` component that helped me figure a few things out

Comment: @drschultz you're right I think. My callback is null (at the end of the async) so it's throwing an exception. how can i get around this?! I'm not afraid to say I'm a little baffled at the moment !

Comment: You'll have to post more of your code so we can see how you're defining/instantiating/implementing your callback. Since that's what's null, we're going to have to dig into that specific code.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the input everyone. I've managed to sort this. I needed a class-wide variable to hold the callback in and a callback handler. Here's my code:

```
public class MyClass extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    private Bitmap mTheImage;
    private Callback mCallback;
    private WritableMap mResults;

    public MyClass(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.mContext = reactContext;
    }

    private void consumeCallback(String type, WritableMap obj) {
        if(mCallback!=null) {
            obj.putString("type", type);

            mCallback.invoke(obj);
            mCallback = null;
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void doMyStuff(final String input, final Callback callback) {
        if(mCallback==null) {
            mResults = Arguments.createMap();
        }

        mCallback = callback;

        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

               try {
                    String myValue = params[0];

                    mResults.putString("myValue", myValue);

                mTheImage = [method to get the image]

                }
                catch(Exception e) {

                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void dummy) {

                if(null!=mTheImage && null!=mCallback) {

                    mResults.putInt("width", mImage.getWidth());
                    mResults.putInt("height",mImage.getHeight());

                    consumeCallback("success", mResults);
                }
                else {
                    consumeCallback("error", mResults);
                }
            }
        }.execute(url);

    }
}
```

Comment: This was a tough one but I learnt a lot about react-native doing it!